# Property $x^y = (x+y)^2$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-function, square-numbers

Solve for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$n=x^y=\left(x+y\right)^2$$
where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z+}$, and $x$ or $y$ is a prime number.

this is the question, I only got a triple $(n,x,y)=(64,2,6)$.

Can someone verify my solution to this? If so, I'll post it in the comments.

Comment: You should post a solution as an answer, not in the comments. Also, you should indicate at least some of your attempt in the question statement.

Comment: $n=x=1, y=0$ is also a solution

Comment: @Andrei i forgot to put that x and y are positive integers

Comment: Then yes, you found the only solution

Comment: I consider your attempt to solve the problem as sufficient context, and so I'm voting to Leave Open.  However the steps to solution given in the Answer could use some polishing to avoid an appearance of leaps in logic.

Answer (score 1):

From $x^y=(x+y)^2$ , we get $x^{y/2}=x+y \implies y=2t$ .

If $y$ is prime, then $y=2$ which gives no solution and $y>2$ because $x^2<(x+y)^2$

So $x$ is prime, therefore if $x\ge5$ we can write $x=5+n$, with $n\ge0$.

$(5+n)^y=(5+n+y)^2$, but $y<3$ because $(5+n)^3>(8+n)^2$ $\forall n\ge0$

thus $3>y>2$ if $x\ge5$

$x=3$ don't give solution and $x=2\implies y=6 $ and $n=64$